# setAssociations mixin with multiple entries and through attributes sequelize and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, polymorphic-associations, sequelize-typescript

What I want to have is a relation between a user profile and the languages this user speaks with each language having a specific proficiency, I've managed to do so via the following schema

```js
export class Profile extends Model {

    public languages?: Language[];

    declare setLanguages: BelongsToManySetAssociationsMixin<Language, number>;
    declare addLanguage: BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin<Language, number>;
    declare addLanguages: BelongsToManyAddAssociationsMixin<Language, number>;
    declare getLanguges: BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin<Language>;

    static associate(models: any) {
        Profile.belongsToMany(models.Language, {
                                  through: models.ProfileLanguage,
                                  as: "languages"
                              })
    }
}
```

```js
class Language extends Model {
    public id!: number;
    public label!: string;

    public properties?: ProfileLanguage;

    static associate(models: any) {
        Language.belongsToMany(models.Profile, { through: models.ProfileLanguage })
    }
}


class ProfileLanguage extends Model {
    public proficiency!: number;
}
```

now to add multiple languages at once to the profile one can use the `setLanguages` mixin however I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how I can add multiple proficiencies since the through property doesn't accept and array in typescript. I achieved what I want using the following

```js
    for(let lang of info.known_languages) {
        await profile.addLanguage(lang.language, {through: {proficiency: lang.proficiency}})
    }
```

however this results in multiple queries which is not optimal, can anyone tell me how to achieve this in one query?
thanks in advance.